# How to change data type in a list of tuples if this type is Timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[
(12, Timestamp(...), 'test_1'),
(14, Timestamp(...), 'test_2')
]
```

What I do is:

```
temp_array = df.to_numpy()

for i, (cols) in enumerate(temp_array):
    for val in cols:
        if type(val) == pd.Timestamp:
            val = np.datetime64(val)

tuples = [tuple(x) for x in temp_array]
```

How can I do to change directly the Timestamp type in this list of tuples ?
More precisely, if type is pd.Timestamp I would like to change it to np.datetime64.

Comment: As tuples are immutable you can't change the timestamp. You could create a list of lists and then change it.

Comment: I tried it with a numpy array (with enumerate) but when I do the data type change it doesn't work when I create my list of tuples after it

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your code, but you would have to add it to your question if you want help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example that should explain what you are missing.

```
my_list = [
    ['12', 123, 'test_1'],
    ['14', 456, 'test_2']
]

print(my_list)

for i, cols in enumerate(my_list):
    for j, val in enumerate(cols):
        if type(val) == int:
            my_list[i][j] = str(val)

print(my_list)
```

The result:

> [['12', 123, 'test_1'], ['14', 456, 'test_2']]
>
> [['12', '123', 'test_1'], ['14', '456', 'test_2']]

So the complete answer is: don't change tuples and use indexes to change the content of your list.

But I would create a new list and not change the existing one.
Something like this:

```
my_list = [
    ['12', 123, 'test_1'],
    ['14', 456, 'test_2']
]

print(my_list)

new_list = [[str(item) if type(item) == int else item for item in cols] for cols in my_list]

print(new_list)
```